# Laravel join with 3 Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, laravel

I am building a Twitter-like app. There is a Feed in which I want to only show posts of Users who I follow.

I tried everything with joins, but nothing seems to work.

I have 3 tables: `Users`, `Followers`, `Shares`

The Tables look like this:

**Users**: `id`

**Followers**: `user_id`, `follower_id`

**Shares**: `user_id`

What I need to get is "ALL Shares WHERE share.user_id = followers.follower_id"
"ANDWHERE followers.user_id = users.id"

Assume, the users.id is 3, I tried this:

```
$shares = DB::table('shares')
        ->leftjoin('followers', 'shares.user_id', '=', 'followers.follower_id')
        ->leftjoin('users', 'followers.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->where('users.id', 3)
        ->where('shares.user_id', 'followers.follower_id')
        ->get();
```

But it doesnt work.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Ideally, you should be retrieving the data you seek in reverse order of your current setup. You would not find all shares and then go backwards. First find your followers, then the shares those followers have. It may be irrelevant in some regards but it definitely makes more sense syntactically.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I believe your join is wrong:

```php
$shares = DB::table('shares')
    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'shares.user_id')
    ->join('followers', 'followers.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->where('followers.follower_id', '=', 3)
    ->get();
```

I also suggest you to name your table as `follows` instead, it feels a bit more natural to say `user has many followers through follows` and `user has many followees through follows`.

**Example**

```php
$shares = DB::table('shares')
    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'shares.user_id')
    ->join('follows', 'follows.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->where('follows.follower_id', '=', 3)
    ->get();
```

### Model approach

I didn't realize you were using `DB::` queries and not models. So I'm fixing the answer and providing a lot more clarity. I suggest you use models, it's a lot easier for those beginning with the framework and specially SQL.

**Example of models:**

```php
class User extends Model {
    public function shares() {
        return $this->hasMany('Share');
    }
    public function followers() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'follows', 'user_id', 'follower_id');
    }
    public function followees() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'follows', 'follower_id', 'user_id');
    }
}
class Share extends Model {
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
}
```

**Example of Model usage:**

```php
$my = User::find('my_id');

// Retrieves all shares by users that I follow
// eager loading the "owner" of the share
$shares = Share::with('user')
    ->join('follows', 'follows.user_id', '=', 'shares.user_id')
    ->where('follows.follower_id', '=', $my->id)
    ->get('shares.*'); // Notice the shares.* here

// prints the username of the person who shared something
foreach ($shares as $share) {
    echo $share->user->username;
}

// Retrieves all users I'm following
$my->followees;

// Retrieves all users that follows me
$my->followers;
```

Comment: Hm, for me it seems right, but somehow it doesnt work. I changed followers.user_id to followers.follower_id and followers.follower_id to followers.user_id, but now it returns just all shares

Comment: Are you storing the id of the user being followed on `followers.user_id`, or are you storing the id of the user following? And are you using `leftjoin` or `join`? Also make sure you are including the `=` on the where clause.

Comment: followers.user_id is the user who is following. follower.follower_id is therefore the id of the user who is followed. I am using join, and i think the "=" is default if not set, but i have set it now

Comment: It should be the inverse, at least english speaking.

Comment: Ye, i have some troubles with the naming .. So I will do it as you said, the table "Follows" and the "follower_id" is the user who follows the "user_id". Is this right?

Comment: Ok alright, but now I have the problem that I cant access the relationships like: $share->user->username

Comment: There you go. I gave a pretty extensive answer :)

Comment: Thank you very, very much! I definitely appreciate it, and would give you reputation +++ but I cant, as I am a new user :/ Stackoverflow isnt allowing

Comment: Great examples :) But how do I combine "get(shares.*)" with paginate? And also, somehow if I do "get(shares.*) it gives me some errors :/ http://paste.laravel.com/Lh7

Comment: Simply use: `paginate(10, 'shares.*')` instead of `get('shares.*')`

Comment: Hm, If I do 'shares.*' I still get this error: paste.laravel.com/Lh7

Comment: You can try paginate(10, array('shares.*')). Strangely the former should work.

Comment: Oh my god, after 4 hours of headache you finally solved the error for me. I am so thankful dude :))) Thanks very, very much!

Comment: One last thing, how do you guys all know these "secret" commands like 'shares.*' ? I read the whole documentation and there just wasnt this kind information.

Comment: I'm glad to hear. Whenever struggling, you should take a look on http://laravel.com/api It contains some pretty useful information on how to use each class and its methods :)

Answer (score 1):

In terms of general MySQL syntax, this is best written:

```
SELECT * FROM USER a JOIN FOLLOWERS b ON (a.id = b.user_id) JOIN SHARES c on (b.follower_id = c.user_id) WHERE a.id = 3
```

will return a data set of all followers and their respective shares.

I believe you would want the following in Laravel

```
DB::table('USER')
  ->join('FOLLOWERS', 'USER.id', '=', 'FOLLOWERS.user_id')
  ->join('SHARES', 'FOLLOWERS.follower_id', '=', 'SHARES.user_id')
  ->where('USER.id', 3)
  ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
    ->where('shares.user_id', 'followers.follower_id')
```

It should be

```
    ->whereRaw('shares.user_id=followers.follower_id')
```

because on the original example the 'followers.follower_id' is interpreted as a string.

Comment: This worked for me... I had an issue with additional duplicate records, that didn't exist, popping up on my join. I had one day record that referenced a rate_id and a user_id and I wanted to show data from days, rates and users. I kept getting two days popping up, one of which didn't exist, because there was a second rate attached to the user but no day for it. I call the position_user relationship rates for better understanding in my software. `->whereRaw('days.rate_id = position_user.id')`

Answer (score 0):

```
$data[shares] = DB::table('shares')
        ->leftjoin('followers', 'shares.user_id', '=', 'followers.follower_id')
        ->leftjoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->where('users.id','=', 3)
        ->get();
```

to see results.

```
print_r($data[shares]);die;
```

for other query Simply give discription of your table

Answer (score 0):

First of all, go through users table and join it with followers table, and then with share table to get corresponding shares data of only followers. Here is the code

```
 $shares = DB::table('users')
->leftjoin('followers', 'users.user_id', '=', 'followers.follower_id')
->leftjoin('shares', 'shares.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
->where('users.id', 3)
->get();
```

Comment: You should edit your answer and describe how or why it answers the question

Comment: I have updated the answer. Upvote if it deserves