# Laravel Eloquent: how to filter reviews of products by product category and/or product brand?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I will describe this situation with more details:

I have a list of products where every product belongs to a certain category and to a certain brand. Some of the products can get reviewed by users.

On /reviews/ page in my Laravel application, I have a list of reviews and select boxes for category and brand along with search button of course.

If user doesn't choose category or brand, all reviews get displayed, paginated, and that's good.

The problem arises when user chooses either category or brand or both and tries to get all the reviews filtered that way.

```
Reviews table fields: ID, user_id(foreign key users.ID), product_id(foreign key products.ID), text
Products table fields: ID, category_id(foreign key categories.ID), brand_id(foreign key brands.ID), name
Categories table fields: ID, name
Brands table fields: ID, name
Users table fields: ID, username
```

When I'm listing reviews, I'm simply using:

```
$reviews = Review::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(5);
```

If I would like to filter reviews by user_id, that would be easy as the reviews table contains user_id column, 
but, how to filter them by product category and/or product brand?

Here are Review, Product and Category models:

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Review extends Model {
    protected $fillable = [];

    public function product() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
    }

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}

<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model {

    protected $fillable = [];

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function reviews() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Review');
    }

    public function category() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }

}


<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model {
    protected $fillable = [];

    public function products() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
    }
}
```

If I use joins, then $review->user->id, $review->user->username, $review->id are not correct, I'm getting reviews.product_id as $review->id, and products.user_id as $review->user->id in blade template.

I was trying this join variant:

```
$reviews_query = Review::orderBy('reviews.id', 'DESC')
            ->Join('products', 'reviews.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
            ->Join('categories', 'products.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
            ->Join('brands', 'products.brand_id', '=', 'brands.id')
            ->Join('users', 'reviews.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
            ->where('reviews.active', '=', 1)
            ->GroupBy('reviews.id')->paginate(5);
```

And this for filtering by category_id:

```
if (Input::has('category_id')){
    $category_id = Input::get('category_id');
    $reviews_query->where('categories.id', $category_id);
}
```

I'm not sure how to correctly address ambiguous ids such us product_id, review_id, user_id in blade template ($review->id, $review->user->id, all are messed up mutually)

Comment: where you are storing review...?

Comment: How do you mean? In reviews database table

Comment: so just check that where for particular product review is stored or not..??you can retrieve only those product

Comment: I don't need products, I need reviews of all the products in a certain category

Answer (score 2):

Add hasManyThrough relationship in your category model

```
public function reviews() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Review', 'App\Product');
}
```

now you can have all reviews by a category like this

```
$category->reviews();
```

you can add other query clauses to it like

```
$category->reviews()->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(5);
```

Comment: That solves the problem with wrong $review->id in blade template and that' s good. I'm wandering how to sub-filter reviews based on Input::get('category_id)? Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$reviews = DB::table('review')
->join('product', 'product.id', '=', 'review.product_id')
->Join('category', 'product.category_id', '=', 'category.id')
->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(5);
```

**for more you can visit-**
[Laravel join with 3 Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18388664/laravel-join-with-3-tables)

This may work for you.....

Comment: That would be good, but makes me error in blade template where I'm getting wrong $review->id

Answer (score 0):

filter all reviews by a specific CategoryID then simply use ->

```
$categoryID = 1;
Categories::with(['products' => function($product){
        $product->with('reviews');
    }])->where('id', '=', $categoryID)->get();
```

also filter all reviews by a specific BrandID then

```
$brandID = 1;
Brands::with(['products' => function($product){
        $product->with('reviews');
    }])->where('id', '=', $brandID)->get();
```