# Laravel 5.3 eloquent 3 table join using models

Tags: laravel, model, eloquent

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18388664/laravel-join-with-3-tables) post which helped, but need more guidance please.

I need a set of Results for a particular `$batteryid` (on Result) and a particular `$age` (on Test model) and a particular `$gender` (from Athlete). Each Test belongs to one athlete. Each test has many results.

Model Battery:

```
class Battery extends Model{
    public function results(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Result');
    }    
}
```

Model Result:

```
class Result extends Model{
    public function test(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Test', 'test_id');
    }

    public function battery(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Battery', 'battery_id');
    }    
}
```

Model Test:

```
class Test extends Model{
    public function athlete(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Athlete', 'athlete_id');
    }

    public function results(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Result');
    }
}
```

I get the correct results with the following, but it's two queries:

```
$tests = Test::whereHas('Athlete', function($query) use($gender){
                $query->wheregender($gender);
           })->where('age', $age)->get();

$test_ids = $tests->pluck('id');
$results = Result::where('battery_id', '=', $battery)
          ->whereIn('test_id', $test_ids)
          ->get();
```

I'd like to use model approach, but am completely stuck. `test.age` not recognised and not sure how to get the age from athlete model. My attempt:

```
            $results = Result::with('test')
            ->where('test.age', '=', $age)
            ->join('batteries', 'batteries.id', '=', 'test.battery_id')
            //->where('test->athlete().gender', '=' $gender)
            ->where('battery_id', '=', $battery)
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `whereHas` for the condition and `with` method for eager loading it.

```
    $results = Result::whereHas('test', function($q) use ($age) {
          $q->where('age', '=', $age);
          $q->whereHas('athlete', function ($q) {
              $q->where('gender', 'male');
          });

        })
        ->with('test')
        ->whereHas('battery', function($q) use($battery) {
            $q->where('battery_id', '=', $battery);
        })
        ->with('battery')
        ->get();
```

Comment: It worked before you added the gender bit. I'm testing different syntax now, perhaps the 2nd $q-> must come out?

Comment: Does your athlete table got gender column?

Comment: If you use `gender` variable, you need to include it in function closure.

Comment: yes, I added use($gender). Also tried the gender hard coded exactly as your code. Getting parse error for unexpected `}`. I've moved things around, not working yet. Works 100% before gender validation.

Comment: I think I fixed it @louisav

Comment: The power of a semi-colon. Thanks so much.

Comment: Hope it helps. Good luck!

Comment: is it good to add these queries in models or controller? My controllers have all my queries and models only have relationships. So is it good to create a function in Result model like `rankData()` and just stick this in there?

Comment: For each result per Test I need to calculate a ranking using the query above, so doesn't the model make more sense? Then I can call the method for each result `{{$result->getRank($age, $gender, $battery)}}` Should I post a question for this?

Comment: @louisav Yes please. That is really a strong opinionated question and deserve another question

Comment: Thanks. It's posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42878964/laravel-query-with-function-belong-in-model-or-controller