# Laravel 5.5 three table join

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Edit: I am using API routes, so i have no views and such

I have a database like this

```
User:
   id
   name

card:
   id
   card_number
   user_id


swipe:
   id
   time
   card_number
```

the relationships go as followed  user has one card one card has many swipe

the joins would be as such

```
user.id = card.user_id
card.card_number = swipe.card_number
```

In Larvel i have 3 models.

```
user
card
swipe
```

user Model

```
class user extends Model
{

    public function card()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\card','user_id','id');
    }

}
```

in a controller if i do

```
$model = user::with('card')->get();
```

i get the card data joined with the user data as expected.

```
class card extends Model
{


    public function person()
    {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\user');
    }

    public function swipe(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\swipe','card_number','card_number');
    }
}
```

if i now do

$model = user::with('card.swipe')->get();

which i would expect to return all the users with their cards, and swipes associated to that card.

However what i get is

500 internal server error

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Turn on debug mode and give us the error message.

Comment: I am using the API Routes so no views or anything, i have debug enabled, but its a 500 internal serve error, nothing gets logged it just dies

Comment: are you sure 'foreign_key', 'local_key' match? `('App\swipe','card_number','card_number')`

Comment: @user3350597 swipe.card_number = card.card_number

Answer (score 0):

**For Example you can use like this.**

```
$shares = DB::table('shares')
    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'shares.user_id')
    ->join('follows', 'follows.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->where('follows.follower_id', '=', 3)
    ->get();
```

Comment: I could, but i want to use eloquent models and relationships

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18388664/laravel-join-with-3-tables) **click here**

Answer (score 0):

You cant use like this,

```
user::with('card.swipe')->get();
```

Use Has many Through

```
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

user - countries (in docs)
card - users (in docs)
swipe - posts (in docs)

$country->posts;
$user->swipe;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is right solution, but you can try:

```
public function swipe(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\swipe')->where('card_number','card_number');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to extract your data in your controller like this:

```
return user::with(['card' => function($query) {
   $query->with('swipe');
}])->get();
```

Make sure your swipe model "belongsTo('App\card')".