# Laravel 5.5, DB query join 3 tables, and group by category

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

I have three tables which I wanna join, and group them by category. something like: "western food" => truck a, truck b
currently, if I have two trucks in same category, it doesn't display in result, it just shows one.

```
tables:
touch_points: id, name

1 | starbucks

2 | kfc

3 | mcdonalds


t_categories: id, name

1 | western food

2 | chinese food

3 | indian food

truck_categories: id, touch_point_id, t_category_id

1 |  1 | 3

2 |  2 | 3

3 |  3 | 4
```

the query I have now is this:

```
 $truck = DB::table('truck_categories')
        ->join('touch_points', 'truck_categories.touch_point_id', '=', 'touch_points.id')
        ->join('t_categories', 't_categories.id', '=', 'truck_categories.t_category_id')
        ->select('t_categories.name', 'touch_points.id')
        ->groupBy('t_categories.name')
        ->get();

    return $truck;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try this group by t_category_id

```
$truck = DB::table('truck_categories')
        ->join('touch_points', 'touch_points.id' , '=', 'truck_categories.touch_point_id')
        ->join('t_categories', 't_categories.id', '=', 'truck_categories.t_category_id')
        ->select('t_categories.name', 'touch_points.id')
        ->groupBy('truck_categories.t_category_id')
        ->get();

    return $truck;
```

Comment: 0 
name: "malay"
truck : "Starbucks"
1 
name: "indian"
truck : "donalds"

I get this, whereas the malay has two trucks, it just displays one, do i need to use a loop?

Answer (score 0):

you may do like this

```
$shares = DB::table('shares')
    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'shares.user_id')
    ->join('follows', 'follows.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->groupBy('currency_list')
    ->get();
```

for more details refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18389121/6186468) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18389121/6186468)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fallow laravel codding standards then you should use ORM like below:

> => For **touch_points**, **t_categories**, **truck_categories** table you have already created **Model** for this.
>
> => Then you need to set relationship for related to table parent and child.
>
> => Related to your table structure you need to add a relation to below:

**truck_categories**

```
class TruckCategory extends Eloquent{

  protected $table = 'truck_categories';  

  public function touchpoint()
  {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\TouchPoint'); // touch_points's model name.
  }
  public function tcategory()
  {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\TCategory'); // t_categories model name.
  }
}
```

**touch_points**

```
class TouchPoint extends Eloquent{

  protected $table = 'touch_points';  

  public function truckcategory()
  {
       return $this->hasMany('App\TruckCategory'); // truck_categories's model name.
  }
}
```

**t_categories**

```
class TCategory extends Eloquent{

  protected $table = 't_categories';  

  public function truckcategory()
  {
       return $this->hasMany('App\TruckCategory'); // truck_categories's model name.
  }
}
```

> => Then data get from all table with group by:

```
 App\TCategory::with('truckcategory')->get();
```

Comment: in t_categories and touch_points model, you sure the relation should be belongsto and not hasmany?

Comment: yeah better now, as I was working on that. now I have a query:

$truck = TCategory::with('truck_categories.touch_points')->get();

json:

"id": 7,
  "name": "indian",
  "created_at": null,
  "updated_at": null,
  "truck_categories": [{
   "id": 10,
   "touch_point_id": 1,
   "t_category_id": 7,
   "created_at": null,
   "updated_at": null,
   "touch_points": {
    "id": 1,
    "brand_id": 1,
    "user_id": 11,
    "base_latitude": 3.149099,
    "base_longitude": 101.762452,
    "name": "Starbucks",...

if there are two trucks in one category it displays fine.

Comment: now the issue is I know use "where" for touch_points, how do i achieve that as my query is this:

$truck = TCategory::with('truck_categories.touch_points')->get();

Comment: You can try like this:

App\TCategory::with(['truckcategory', 'touchpoint' => function($query){
                    $query->where('<put your code here>');                               
}])->get();

Thanks,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169824/discussion-between-pratik-mehta-and-hashaam-ahmed).